# Glide caching in Android RecyclerView not working

Tags: android, caching, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm using Glide image library (4.8) on an Android application to load images from url into an image view inside a recyclerview cell.

It seems like caching does not work, as I still get kind of "flickering" when I scroll the recycler view. I also put the phone in plane mode to confirm that images were not loading from a local cache and indeed, images were no longer loaded.

Do I need a specific set-up to get the caching work ? I was expecting it to be enabled by default from the documentation.